# Coccinelle help to replace a function with variable args

Tags: coccinelle

I have something like this

```
void test_fn(int a, ...)
{
 ...
}
int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int b,a1,a2,a3;
....
b = test_fn(a1,a2,a3);
return 0;
}
```

I want to replace test_fn with a different function func_1. Both test_fn and func_1 have variable arguments. 
What I want is

```
test_fn(a1,a2,a3)// to be replaced by
func_1(x1,a2,a3)
```

i.e I want to replace the first arg with a different one and retain all other args.

I'm brand new to coccinelle and I came up with this with a bit of googling

```
@@ expression E;
identifier test_fn;@@
-test_fn(E, ...)
+func_1(x)
```

Not sure how to add the variable args though. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is the "expression list"

So assuming I have a macro or fucntion call ed LOGPLCFN() which accepts a variadic argument list, but I'd like to swap the argument order  within the first few (fixed) arguments, I can declare the first 4 arguments as "expression" and then one "expression list" for  the trailer of the arguments.  This can then be substituted-in in the "+" line

```
@@
expression lc, ss, logl, fn;
expression list trailer;
@@

-LOGPLCFN(lc, ss, logl, fn, trailer);
+LOGPLCFN(lc, fn, ss, logl, trailer);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the easiest way to deal with this is to realize that you do not need to match the lines for the replacement code.

```
@@
expression E;
@@
- bar(E,
+ foo(
  ...
  )
```